# Energy loss rate as a function of alpha particle energy ($\Delta E/ \Delta x$ vs. $E$)

Tags: nuclear-physics

I'm trying to understand the energy loss rate of alpha particles in air and . I have this plot (below) but I don't really understand what it means. $\Delta E/  \Delta x$ is the change in energy as the alpha particle travels through air and the energy on the x-axis is the energy of the alpha particle at different distances.

[image]

Comment: What is the question?  What are the units on *y*?

Comment: Basically, you should get some Bragg curve, that goes up, down and then is semiconstant. The interpretation is - how large are losses per unit distance passed by alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but anyway, your graph is wrong. It is more likely something like energy at a distance.

The dE/dx should look like **the second column in the next table**. Helium in air, STD conditions. You can see maximum of losses at 600-700 keV.  Particle loose energy on their way down to zero (in large enough material thickness). At some place, the damage to material is higher than at other places - it is when energy is at maximal losses regime.

```
       Ion        dE/dx      dE/dx     Projected  Longitudinal   Lateral
       Energy      Elec.      Nuclear     Range     Straggling   Straggling
  --------------  ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------  ----------
  10.00 keV   5.171E-02  9.960E-03  132.97 um    54.63 um    47.80 um  
  11.00 keV   5.423E-02  9.449E-03  145.40 um    57.65 um    51.05 um  
  12.00 keV   5.664E-02  8.996E-03  157.64 um    60.46 um    54.14 um  
  13.00 keV   5.895E-02  8.591E-03  169.68 um    63.08 um    57.08 um  
  14.00 keV   6.117E-02  8.226E-03  181.52 um    65.53 um    59.89 um  
  15.00 keV   6.332E-02  7.896E-03  193.17 um    67.84 um    62.57 um  
  16.00 keV   6.540E-02  7.595E-03  204.65 um    70.00 um    65.14 um  
  17.00 keV   6.741E-02  7.319E-03  215.95 um    72.05 um    67.60 um  
  18.00 keV   6.936E-02  7.066E-03  227.08 um    73.98 um    69.97 um  
  20.00 keV   7.311E-02  6.615E-03  248.86 um    77.56 um    74.43 um  
  22.50 keV   7.755E-02  6.136E-03  275.24 um    81.57 um    79.56 um  
  25.00 keV   8.174E-02  5.731E-03  300.76 um    85.13 um    84.27 um  
  27.50 keV   8.573E-02  5.382E-03  325.48 um    88.33 um    88.62 um  
  30.00 keV   8.954E-02  5.078E-03  349.48 um    91.23 um    92.65 um  
  32.50 keV   9.320E-02  4.811E-03  372.81 um    93.86 um    96.40 um  
  35.00 keV   9.672E-02  4.574E-03  395.51 um    96.27 um    99.91 um  
  37.50 keV   1.001E-01  4.362E-03  417.65 um    98.48 um   103.20 um  
  40.00 keV   1.034E-01  4.171E-03  439.24 um   100.52 um   106.29 um  
  45.00 keV   1.097E-01  3.840E-03  480.98 um   104.24 um   111.98 um  
  50.00 keV   1.156E-01  3.564E-03  520.96 um   107.48 um   117.09 um  
  55.00 keV   1.212E-01  3.328E-03  559.39 um   110.34 um   121.73 um  
  60.00 keV   1.266E-01  3.125E-03  596.44 um   112.88 um   125.97 um  
  65.00 keV   1.317E-01  2.948E-03  632.23 um   115.16 um   129.86 um  
  70.00 keV   1.366E-01  2.792E-03  666.90 um   117.22 um   133.46 um  
  80.00 keV   1.460E-01  2.529E-03  733.25 um   120.97 um   139.91 um  
  90.00 keV   1.547E-01  2.316E-03  796.14 um   124.15 um   145.55 um  
 100.00 keV   1.628E-01  2.139E-03  856.07 um   126.88 um   150.56 um  
 110.00 keV   1.706E-01  1.989E-03  913.45 um   129.27 um   155.04 um  
 120.00 keV   1.779E-01  1.861E-03  968.59 um   131.38 um   159.10 um  
 130.00 keV   1.848E-01  1.750E-03    1.02 mm   133.27 um   162.79 um  
 140.00 keV   1.915E-01  1.652E-03    1.07 mm   134.96 um   166.18 um  
 150.00 keV   1.978E-01  1.566E-03    1.12 mm   136.51 um   169.31 um  
 160.00 keV   2.038E-01  1.489E-03    1.17 mm   137.91 um   172.21 um  
 170.00 keV   2.096E-01  1.420E-03    1.22 mm   139.20 um   174.92 um  
 180.00 keV   2.152E-01  1.358E-03    1.26 mm   140.40 um   177.44 um  
 200.00 keV   2.257E-01  1.249E-03    1.35 mm   142.80 um   182.05 um  
 225.00 keV   2.377E-01  1.138E-03    1.46 mm   145.55 um   187.13 um  
 250.00 keV   2.487E-01  1.046E-03    1.56 mm   147.93 um   191.60 um  
 275.00 keV   2.586E-01  9.687E-04    1.66 mm   150.03 um   195.60 um  
 300.00 keV   2.675E-01  9.031E-04    1.75 mm   151.92 um   199.22 um  
 325.00 keV   2.757E-01  8.464E-04    1.84 mm   153.62 um   202.52 um  
 350.00 keV   2.830E-01  7.970E-04    1.93 mm   155.18 um   205.56 um  
 375.00 keV   2.895E-01  7.534E-04    2.02 mm   156.62 um   208.38 um  
 400.00 keV   2.954E-01  7.147E-04    2.10 mm   157.96 um   211.02 um  
 450.00 keV   3.051E-01  6.489E-04    2.27 mm   161.24 um   215.83 um  
 500.00 keV   3.125E-01  5.950E-04    2.43 mm   164.21 um   220.16 um  
 550.00 keV   3.178E-01  5.499E-04    2.58 mm   166.95 um   224.12 um  
 600.00 keV   3.212E-01  5.116E-04    2.74 mm   169.53 um   227.80 um  
 650.00 keV   3.231E-01  4.786E-04    2.89 mm   171.97 um   231.25 um  
 700.00 keV   3.236E-01  4.500E-04    3.05 mm   174.33 um   234.53 um  
 800.00 keV   3.214E-01  4.024E-04    3.36 mm   181.50 um   240.70 um  
 900.00 keV   3.160E-01  3.645E-04    3.67 mm   188.45 um   246.52 um  
   1.00 MeV   3.085E-01  3.335E-04    3.99 mm   195.34 um   252.14 um  
   1.10 MeV   2.999E-01  3.077E-04    4.32 mm   202.27 um   257.64 um  
   1.20 MeV   2.907E-01  2.858E-04    4.65 mm   209.32 um   263.10 um  
   1.30 MeV   2.814E-01  2.670E-04    5.00 mm   216.52 um   268.58 um  
   1.40 MeV   2.722E-01  2.507E-04    5.36 mm   223.92 um   274.11 um  
   1.50 MeV   2.632E-01  2.363E-04    5.74 mm   231.53 um   279.73 um  
   1.60 MeV   2.547E-01  2.237E-04    6.12 mm   239.37 um   285.46 um  
   1.70 MeV   2.466E-01  2.123E-04    6.52 mm   247.44 um   291.32 um  
   1.80 MeV   2.390E-01  2.022E-04    6.93 mm   255.73 um   297.32 um  
   2.00 MeV   2.250E-01  1.847E-04    7.79 mm   286.23 um   309.82 um  
   2.25 MeV   2.099E-01  1.669E-04    8.94 mm   332.72 um   326.45 um  
   2.50 MeV   1.969E-01  1.524E-04   10.17 mm   378.95 um   344.29 um  
   2.75 MeV   1.856E-01  1.403E-04   11.47 mm   425.25 um   363.39 um  
   3.00 MeV   1.757E-01  1.301E-04   12.86 mm   471.81 um   383.78 um  
   3.25 MeV   1.669E-01  1.214E-04   14.31 mm   518.75 um   405.48 um  
   3.50 MeV   1.591E-01  1.138E-04   15.85 mm   566.14 um   428.47 um  
   3.75 MeV   1.521E-01  1.072E-04   17.45 mm   614.03 um   452.76 um  
   4.00 MeV   1.458E-01  1.013E-04   19.13 mm   662.46 um   478.33 um  
   4.50 MeV   1.347E-01  9.140E-05   22.69 mm   840.22 um   533.24 um  
   5.00 MeV   1.253E-01  8.335E-05   26.54 mm     1.01 mm   593.05 um  
   5.50 MeV   1.172E-01  7.666E-05   30.66 mm     1.17 mm   657.62 um  
   6.00 MeV   1.102E-01  7.102E-05   35.05 mm     1.34 mm   726.81 um  
   6.50 MeV   1.040E-01  6.619E-05   39.72 mm     1.50 mm   800.50 um  
   7.00 MeV   9.853E-02  6.201E-05   44.65 mm     1.66 mm   878.60 um  
   8.00 MeV   8.919E-02  5.512E-05   55.31 mm     2.26 mm     1.05 mm  
   9.00 MeV   8.241E-02  4.967E-05   66.97 mm     2.81 mm     1.23 mm  
  10.00 MeV   7.604E-02  4.524E-05   79.59 mm     3.35 mm     1.43 mm  
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Multiply Stopping by        for Stopping Units
 -------------------        ------------------
  1.0000E-01                 eV / Angstrom 
  1.0000E+00                keV / micron   
  1.0000E+00                MeV / mm
```

Answer (score 0):

What the graph represents is simply energy loss per unit distance for a given alpha energy. I am guessing that the units of the y axis are something like keV/cm. It shows that the rate of energy loss increases for increasing alpha energy or conversely that the rate of energy loss decreases as an alpha particle slows down.

The way this graph was probably generated is as follows.
Take a collimated alpha source and alpha detector with good energy resolution such as a "PIPS". Position the detector at your starting distance D0 and measure alpha energy E0 (in this case about 5.5 MeV), move the detector to distance D1 and measure corresponding energy E1. You can then calculate ΔE/Δx i.e. (D0-D1)/(E0-E1) which you will correspond to average energy loss rate between E0 and E1 which you could take to be the midpoint of the two energies i.e. (E0+E1)/2. You then have a data point for your energy loss rate vs energy graph. Then move the detector to D2 and measure the energy E2 and carry on like this until you have populated the graph.